# Is clock_gettime a UTC time, or local time zone?

Tags: linux, posix

Does the function `clock_gettime` return a timestamp measured from the epoch in UTC or in the local time zone?

I know that `time` is supposed to be from the UTC epoch, but I can't find any reference saying the same is true of `clock_gettime`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To quote Wikipedia, the Unix Epoch is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as

> the time 00:00:00 **UTC** on 1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601).

From this it follows that any reference to "the Epoch" implies UTC.

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion. absolute time events have no time zones.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually, I don't think there's any disagreement between the two of us. The timezone (UTC) only comes into play when we express that "absolute time event" with reference to the local date/time *in a particular place*.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the question does not make a lot of sense. See [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) for an overview of time-related functions.

Any clock device returns a time measured from some origin event in the past. Unix (and Posix) convention is to measure it from the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (start of 1970, as [aix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531888/841108) explains).

*Displaying* some time in UTC, or local time, or using the French revolutionary calendar, or using the Maya calendar, or any other calendar from whatever culture you are interested in, does not change that time. Only the display (or shown form) of that time changes.

It is a bit like saying that *two*, *deux*, *1+1*, or *2*, or 10b -with *b* meaning binary- are all representations of the *same* number.

Back to the question, the [man page of clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) gives the precise answer to the question. It depends upon the *`clk_id`* you are asking for, and for `CLOCK_REALTIME`, the time is measured since the Unix Epoch. For other clocks (e.g. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`), the used origin is not specified.

(I'm quite sadly surprised by the number of questions here which could be answered very quickly by looking into the *man*. I don't understand the logic of people taking more time to ask the question here that to look -just by typing  `man clock_gettime` on their Linux box- into the man pages).

The notion of time zone is only relevant for `struct tm` as returned by [localtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) &  `gmtime` (and related) functions. A time (e.g. some `time_t`) measured from the Epoch (like the result of [time(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time), [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME`) has no time zone.

The Unix Epoch is january 01, 1970 0:00 UTC (by definition of `(time_t)0`), In my time zone (MET= Paris/France) the same Epoch is Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 MET 1970.

Comment: My confusion comes exactly from reading the man page. It only says `Epoch` and gives no definition, whereas time clearly shows the epoch as UTC based. And in both parts of my question I indicate I'm measuring _from_ some time, so I don't see how the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, the Epoch is not UTC based. As any other precise time. You cannot say that the 9/11/2001 events in New year happen in UTC, they just happened at some precise time (whose representation in UTC is not the same as its representation using the French revolutionnary calendar). I insist: a given time event has no time zone! What you can say is that the Epoch, represented in UTC, is 1970, 01 january 0:00. Using the French revolutionnary calendar the same Epoch is  11 Nivôse an 178 (and I forgot how to compute the hour at Paris in that time). But it is the same Epoch time event!

Comment: Sorry, I meant in New York (not New year!)

Answer (score 2):

Just to flesh these answers out a bit:

`clock_gettime()`, the POSIX standard function takes a first parameter for the clock-identifier.

At the time of writing, a common identifier is `CLOCK_REALTIME` which does indeed fetch the UTC Epoch Time - assuming the UNIX clock is correctly set.

There is also `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, which is a clock set from an *unspecified* time-point in the past.  Typically I've seen this implemented as time since process invocation.

And the obligatory example:

```
struct timespec epochTime;
struct timespec otherTime;

// fetch the system time in UTC
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &epochTime );  // CLOCK_REALTIME returns 1970 Epoch Time

// Fetch some equally-valid time, but with an unknown start
// But relative comparisons are absolutely OK
clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &otherTime );
```

Answer (score -1):

it depends..

if you call `clock_gettime(1)`, it is likely, the the epoch is the time when your linux has started.